# Seperate PHP Page, Loop through MySQL table, and Create New Divs

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

I am curious is it possible to create a loop in a separate PHP page that will create divs? Here is what I have been working on. I know that it will show the results for the first row in the data table. However, it does not show the following rows. I would assume since it does not show the following this won't work.

Separte PHP page

```
$query = "SELECT `ID`, `fullname`, `comment`, `date` FROM `reviews`";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(!$result)
  {
    die('Error: ' .mysql_error());
  }
  $row_count = mysql_num_rows($result);
  $row_users = mysql_fetch_array($result);

  for($i=0; $i<$row_count; $i++)
  {
    $results = '<div class="col-lg-4">Name:'.($row_users['fullname']).'<br>'.($row_users['comment']).'<br>Date: '.($row_users['date']).'</div>';
  }
```

Webpage

```
  <div class="row">
    <?php {echo $results;}?>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Create Div for Each MySQL Row

### In PHP file that contains proper database information.

```
function getTable() {
    $query = "SELECT `ID`, `fullname`, `comment`, `date` FROM `reviews`";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    $table = '';

    if ($result) {
        while($row_users = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $table .= "<div class='row'>";
            $table .= '<div class="col-lg-4">Name:'.($row_users['fullname']).'<br>'.($row_users['comment']).'<br>Date: '.($row_users['date']).'</div>';
            $table .= "</div>";
        }
    } else {
        die('Error: ' .mysql_error());
    }

    return $table;
}
```

### In HTML display file

```
<?php echo getTable(); ?>
```

### PHP mysql Extension is deprecated!!!

The extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0 and is removed in PHP 7.0.0.

Do not use the `mysql` class in PHP.  It is not safe.  Please use a library like [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or, my favorite, [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: What do you mean by `PHP MySQL is deprecated!!!`?  PHP MYSQL is not deprecteed! Just mysql() functions are deprecated!!

Comment: @JayPatel Wow I worded that horribly.  Thank you for commenting

Comment: I will looking into adopting one of the following if I can make this work. What I mean is that I have a separate page where I have most of my PHP written that I include with the webpage /testimonials.php

Comment: @MatthewKelsay I have updated my answer.  Now the code is in a function.  So as long as the proper file is `included` or `required` just call the function and it will return the complete table.

Comment: That works perfect! Will take a look a into using one of the library's.

Comment: @MatthewKelsay Glad I could help.  And thank you for taking the effort to keep your code secure and up to date!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
$query = "SELECT `ID`, `fullname`, `comment`, `date` FROM `reviews`";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(!$result)
  {
    die('Error: ' .mysql_error());
  }
  $results = ""
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $results .= '<div class="col-lg-4">Name:'.($row['fullname']).'<br>'.($row['comment']).'<br>Date: '.($row['date']).'</div>';
  }
```

Here, you have to concate `results` string in each loop.
You should user `mysqli_query()` instead of `mysql_query()` as `mysql_` is deprecated.

Comment: You are missing the div for the row.  This will just make a really big single row.

Comment: When I try this it will only show the last row in the data table.

Comment: @HurricaneDevelopment: Thanks!